# distinguish between instances of class

Tags: python

Im completly new to Python. Following this guide: http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php/Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod

I have a simple question: When all the monsters have been created here, how does python distinguish between each instance of the class? As far as i can tell, all the instances are named "monster".

```
def place_objects(room):
#choose random number of monsters
num_monsters = libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, MAX_ROOM_MONSTERS)

for i in range(num_monsters):
    #choose random spot for this monster
    x = libtcod.random_get_int(0, room.x1, room.x2)
    y = libtcod.random_get_int(0, room.y1, room.y2)

    #only place it if the tile is not blocked
    if not is_blocked(x, y):
        if libtcod.random_get_int(0, 0, 100) < 80:  #80% chance of getting an orc
            #create an orc
            fighter_component = Fighter(hp=10, defense=0, power=3, death_function=monster_death)
            ai_component = BasicMonster()

            monster = Object(x, y, 'o', 'orc', libtcod.desaturated_green,
                blocks=True, fighter=fighter_component, ai=ai_component)
        else:
            #create a troll
            fighter_component = Fighter(hp=16, defense=1, power=4, death_function=monster_death)
            ai_component = BasicMonster()

            monster = Object(x, y, 'T', 'troll', libtcod.darker_green,
                blocks=True, fighter=fighter_component, ai=ai_component)

        objects.append(monster)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each object is stored at different memory location. That's how you differentiate.

Use the builtin function id()

```
id(object) 
Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
```

Documentation also says

> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
>   memory.

Example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> x = Foo()
>>> y = Foo()
>>> id (x)
17385736
>>> id (y)
20391336
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, and how do i fetch an object with a certain ID?

Comment: In general, we don't do that. There is no need to. Use the references to keep record of objects & use them. It's not C or C++.

Comment: So lets say that i want to check a monsters status in the console (or whatever its called). Is that not possible? Just for debugging purposes

Comment: @Johan Make sure that you have all the instances of monster in objects list to play with. [ Note the last line objects.append(monster), you are appending all instances to a list ]. I actually couldn't understand what you meant to ask.

Comment: All monsters has got an "hp" attribute. I would like to know if theres a way to check the hp on a certain monster. I cant really write `print monster.hp` unless im looping thorugh all the instances, right?

Comment: @Johan To get a [debugging](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) prompt, just insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` where you want a breakpoint. Use [this code structure](http://pastebin.com/Pz0ASAg6) to enable post-mortem debugging.

Comment: Iterating through the list is a way or if you want to access hp of third monster you created, use `print objects[2].hp`

Answer (score 1):

Creating different identical instances of a class produces different objects, which have different ids.

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> 
>>> x = A()
>>> y = A()
>>> z = A()
>>> x
<__main__.A object at 0x10049dbd0>
>>> y
<__main__.A object at 0x10049db90>
>>> z
<__main__.A object at 0x10049dc10>
>>> x == y
False
>>>
```

also different hash codes

```
>>> x.__hash__()
268737981
>>> y.__hash__()
268737977
>>> z.__hash__()
268737985

>>> x.__hash__() == y.__hash__()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Python (CPython) uses reference counting to keep track of the objects.

This line creates an object and binds it to a name.

```
foo = MyObject()
```

The object is now referenced by one entity (the `foo` name) so its reference count is `1`.

When you create a new reference, the count is increased. When you delete a reference, the count is decreased.

```
baz = foo
```

This created a new reference so now it's `2`.

Now say all this was in a function:

```
def test():
    foo = MyObject()
    baz = foo
```

After the function is done executing, all its local variables are deleted. This means they stop referencing the objects and the counts go down. In this case the count will reach `0` and `MyObject` instance will be freed from memory.

**To keep objects alive, you have to keep references to them. If you don't have a reference, the object itself is most likely gone already.**

That's why your code collects all monsters in a list called `objects` (`objects.append(monster)`). A list will increment the count of every object it contains so when you re-bind the name "monster" to another instance, the previous instance will not be deleted.

The only thing you're missing is:

```
objects = []
```

at the start of your function and:

```
return objects
```

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**We don't have variables in python, just names (references): that are like tags attached to the their value (take a look [[here]](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)).**

So when you do:

```
monster = Object(x, y, 'T', 'troll')
```

You're just attaching the name "monster" to the instance of `Object('troll')`, and when you do:

```
objects.append(monster)
```

You're attaching the tag `objects[0]` to that instance.

This means that when you do again the loop and the tag "monster" is moved onto another instance, of `Object('orc')` for example, you don't lose the instance of `Object('troll')` because there's at least one tag attached to it: `objects[0]`.

So you really have no need of keeping tracks of every instance, you just need to call the right tag.

I hope this helped you clear some of your doubts on how python works.